# Field update a custom opportunity field from opportunity product standard quantity field

Tags: process-builder

I am trying to create a process builder that triggers when a specific product is added to an opp. I want the Quantity sold for that specific product to go into a custom field on the opportunity record. I feel like this should be very straightforward:

1. Process is on Opportunity Product object
2. Criteria is that the product id = "specific product id"
3. immediate action is a field update on opp record related to the opp product record and is a formula field to fill in the value for  OpportunityProduct.Quantity.

This is not firing though. The field on my opp record remains blank. What am I missing here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be much easier to assist you if you give more specifics about your process. Please **[edit]** your post to include some informative screenshots.

Comment: You should not filter on hard coded Id values. Filter on  the name of the product or a unique identifier instead. It may not fix your issue, but it is very important you not leave your criteria node the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Laura Babb dont use the  formula  in update action use Field Reference try like this  it will update
[image]